# A Sparse Format from command stat

Tags: ls, bsd, stat

I'd like to check the status my directories

```
    $ ls
    Foo   Bar  Zoo
```

Check their status

```
    $ ls | xargs stat -x
      File: "Zoo"
      Size: 384          FileType: Directory
      Mode: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)         Uid: (  501/ ..)  Gid: (   20/   ..)
    Device: 1,4   Inode: 8603392907    Links: 12
    Access: Fri Mar 30 09:12:06 2018
    Modify: Wed Mar 28 10:07:32 2018
    Change: Wed Mar 28 10:07:32 2018
      File: "Bar"
      Size: 160          FileType: Directory
      Mode: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)         Uid: (  501/  ..)  Gid: (   20/   ..)
    Device: 1,4   Inode: 8604964551    Links: 5
    Access: Fri Mar 30 09:12:06 2018
    Modify: Thu Mar 29 20:48:46 2018
    Change: Thu Mar 29 20:48:46 2018
      File: "Zoo"
      Size: 416          FileType: Directory
      Mode: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)         Uid: (  501/  ..)  Gid: (   20/   ..)
    Device: 1,4   Inode: 8603830641    Links: 13
    Access: Fri Mar 30 09:28:54 2018
    Modify: Fri Mar 30 09:28:54 2018
    Change: Fri Mar 30 09:28:54 2018
```

The format is dense, I prefer a sparse format to distingish each file or dir intuitively.

```
    $ ls | xargs stat -x
      File: "Foo"
      Size: 384          FileType: Directory
      Mode: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)         Uid: (  501/ ..)  Gid: (   20/   ..)
    Device: 1,4   Inode: 8603392907    Links: 12
    Access: Fri Mar 30 09:12:06 2018
    Modify: Wed Mar 28 10:07:32 2018
    Change: Wed Mar 28 10:07:32 2018

      File: "Bar"
      Size: 160          FileType: Directory
      Mode: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)         Uid: (  501/  ..)  Gid: (   20/   ..)
    Device: 1,4   Inode: 8604964551    Links: 5
    Access: Fri Mar 30 09:12:06 2018
    Modify: Thu Mar 29 20:48:46 2018
    Change: Thu Mar 29 20:48:46 2018

      File: "Zoo"
      Size: 416          FileType: Directory
      Mode: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)         Uid: (  501/  ..)  Gid: (   20/   ..)
    Device: 1,4   Inode: 8603830641    Links: 13
    Access: Fri Mar 30 09:28:54 2018
    Modify: Fri Mar 30 09:28:54 2018
    Change: Fri Mar 30 09:28:54 2018
```

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using BSD stat, you can use the `-f` option to specify the format explicitly, including any trailing new lines you want. Writing out the entire format string for `-x` by hand might be a bit tedious, so here's the format string obtained [from the source](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/usr.bin/stat/stat.c#L108), combined into a single string:

```
'  File: "%N"%n  Size: %-11z  FileType: %HT%n  Mode: (%OMp%03OLp/%.10Sp)         Uid: (%5u/%8Su)  Gid: (%5g/%8Sg)%nDevice: %Hd,%Ld   Inode: %i    Links: %l%nAccess: %Sa%nModify: %Sm%nChange: %Sc'
```

Add a couple of `%n` to the end to get the effect you want:

```
$ stat_format='  File: "%N"%n  Size: %-11z  FileType: %HT%n  Mode: (%OMp%03OLp/%.10Sp)         Uid: (%5u/%8Su)  Gid: (%5g/%8Sg)%nDevice: %Hd,%Ld   Inode: %i    Links: %l%nAccess: %Sa%nModify: %Sm%nChange: %Sc%n%n'
$ stat -f "${stat_format}"  .zshrc .bashrc
  File: ".zshrc"
  Size: 5878         FileType: Regular File
  Mode: (0644/-rw-r--r--)         Uid: (  502/muru)  Gid: (   20/   muru)
Device: 1,5   Inode: 8596072804    Links: 1
Access: Mar 30 11:40:18 2018
Modify: Mar 26 13:34:14 2018
Change: Mar 26 13:34:14 2018

  File: ".bashrc"
  Size: 3768         FileType: Regular File
  Mode: (0644/-rw-r--r--)         Uid: (  502/muru)  Gid: (   20/   muru)
Device: 1,5   Inode: 8593701774    Links: 1
Access: Mar 30 11:40:18 2018
Modify: Jan 28 11:15:12 2018
Change: Jan 28 11:15:12 2018
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do what you want. One of the simplest is the following:

```
$ ls | xargs stat -x | sed 'n;n;n;n;n;n;s/$/\n/'
```

Note - The number of `n;`s may be off by one as I am not on a system that supports the `-x` output option.

Comment: I upvoted, the command `ls | xargs stat -x | sed 'n;n;n;n;n;n;s/$/\n/` output the same without separating each files.

Comment: Are you saying that the `sed` command did not work for you?

Comment: Yes, BSD   --version May 10, 2005

Comment: Ah, the BSD version of `sed` is different.  Try `sed 's/$/\NEWLINE/'`
 i.e. replace NEWLINE with an actual newline.